# Is every sufficiently large positive integer of the form $ab + ac + bc + 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Is every sufficiently large positive integer $A$ of the form $ab + ac + bc + 1$

where $a,b,c$ are some positive integers larger than some given positive integer $d$ ?

How large is sufficiently large , in other words how do we know our number $A$ is sufficiently large ( as a function of $d$ ) ?

---

Update :

I read the following about positive integers that are not of the form $ ab + ac + bc $:

https://oeis.org/A000926

And I quote about that sequence above :
" Note that for n in this sequence, n+1 is either a prime, twice a prime, the square of a prime, 8 or 16 "

This is why I considered the weird +1 in $ab + ac + bc + 1$

So composites larger than 16 not a prime , twice a prime or the square of a prime are of the form $ab + ac + bc + 1$.

And I wonder why !

I guess that relates strongly to the Original posted problem.
Maybe I should have mentioned that before , sorry.

Will Jagy's answer gave the same OEIS link which I already knew.
This also explains some of the comments.

Im no expert in genus theory or Galois theory but I assume this has a simple answer.

---

Comment: I don't think you can determine "sufficently large" as a function of $d$, since $a,b,c$ can be arbitrarily *larger* than $d$. Whatever function $f(d)$ you determine, there's nothing stopping $a=f(d)+1$.

Comment: What is the reason for the $+1$? It seems simpler to ask about numbers of the form $ab+ac+bc$, and is clearly equivalent...

Comment: @Micah I was thinking about writing composites in the form ab + ac + bc + 1 ... but you are right I guess.

Comment: I updated the question.
Really wonder why almost every composite is of the form ab + ac + bc + 1 See the update.
Will probably accept as answer once that is explained.

Answer (score 3):

> Euler's "numerus idoneus" (or "numeri idonei", or idoneal, or
>   suitable, or convenient numbers).

https://oeis.org/A000926

> It is conjectured that the list given here is complete. Chowla showed
>   that the list is finite and Weinberger showed that there is at most
>   one further term.
>
> (6) n is not of the form ab+ac+bc with 0 < a < b < c. [Rains]

Answer (score 2):

Then equation:  $$XY+XZ+YZ=N$$

If we ask what ever number: $p$

That the following sum can always be factored: $p^2+N=ks$

Solutions can be written.  $$X=p$$  $$Y=s-p$$  $$Z=k-p$$

I like this formula the solutions of this equation.  [Number of solution for $xy +yz + zx = N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419766/number-of-solution-for-xy-yz-zx-n/708100#708100)

Comment: +1 I looked at your profile, you certainly like small diophantine equations !
I was fascinated.
I edited my question, maybe you can adress the update with a new answer ?