# $\frac{1}{n}$ as a difference of Egyptian fractions with all denominators $<n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, egyptian-fractions

Is there a good characterization of the set $S$ of positive integers $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}$ can be represented as a difference of Egyptian fractions with all denominators $< n$?
For example, $44 \in S$ because
$$ \dfrac{1}{44} = \left( \frac{1}{33} + \frac{1}{12}\right) - \frac{1}{11} $$

If I'm not mistaken, the first few members of $S$ are
$$ 6, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21, 24, 28, 30, 33, 35, 36, 40, 42, 44, 45 $$
This does not appear to be in the OEIS yet; I intend to submit it soon.
[ EDIT: It is now in OEIS as [A278638](https://oeis.org/A278638).]

Here are some things I know so far:

1. If $n \in S$, then $mn \in S$ for any positive integer $m$.
2. $mn \in S$ for integers $m,n$ with  $n < m < 2 n$, because $$\dfrac{1}{mn} = \dfrac{1}{n(m-n)} - \dfrac{1}{m(m-n)}$$
3. $S$ contains no prime or prime power.
4. There are no members of the form $2p^k$ where $p$ is a prime $> 3$.
5. There are no members of the form $3p^k$ where $p$ is a prime $> 11$.

Comment: If you want to describe the solutions of this equation, using this formula.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419766/number-of-solution-for-xy-yz-zx-n/713998#713998  Or use a different approach.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450280/erd%C5%91s-straus-conjecture/831870#831870

Comment: An interesting subset are made the numbers n where $1/n$ is given by only two terms. I believe for the OP’s sequence from 6 to 45 that is the case for most numbers except 21, 33 and the PO’s example 44.
Examples for 21 and 33 are: $1/21= 1/7+1/14 – (1/10+1/15)$, and $1/33= 1/15+1/10-(1/22+1/11)$.

Comment: One thing to note: Given property 1 it is useful to consider the set $S'$ such that for all $n\in S'$, there is no proper divisor of $n$ in $S'$ (then $S=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}nS'$). Then the proper generalization of properties 4-5 is there are no members of $S'$ of the form $np^k$ where $p$ is a prime $>H_n \text{lcm}(1,\dots, n)$ where $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number.

Comment: Can someone explain the meaning of 'characterisation' in this context. As, it seems to me that the question already lists a plethora of properties of $\mathbb{S}$.

Comment: @DevashishKaushik characterization = necessary and sufficient condition (ideally one that can be easily tested).

Comment: @Robert  Thanks. So, the question is basically asking for a necessary and sufficient condition for a natural number, $n$ to be in the set, $\mathbb{S}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  Are the (even) perfect numbers a subsequence of [OEIS A278638](https://oeis.org/A278638)?

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris Yes because (regardless of whether $p$ or $2^p-1$ is prime)
$2^{p-1}(2^p-1) = m n$ where $m = 2^{p-1}$ and $n = 2^p-1$, and $m < n < 2m$.

Comment: That is interesting!  How about the *odd* perfect numbers (OPNs)?  I know that OPNs must have the Eulerian form $q^k t^2$, where $q$ is the *special* prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,t)=1$.  In particular, I can take $q^k t^2 = mn$, where $m = q^k$ and $n = t^2$, and $m < n$.  Alas, **I am not so sure** about $t^2 = n < 2m = 2q^k$.

Answer (score 3):

*Partial answer.* It shows for example that if $N$ is large enough and satisfies  $P^*(N)^2\leq N$ then $N\in S$. (I think that the methods used in the paper are powerful enough to answer the question completely, In Progress)

---

The condition that the exceptions are tiny multiple of prime powers reminded me of the studies of representing the unity as the sum of Egyptian fractions by P. Erdös, E. S. Croot, and G. Martins.

After some google search, I found the following paper by Greg Martin, [Denser Egyptian fractions](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa95/aa9533.pdf), Acta Arith.

Let for any $y>1$ a real number, $\pi^*(y)$ denote the number of prime powers less than $y$, and for any positive integer $n$, $P^∗(n)$ denote the largest prime power dividing $n$.

In the above paper, it is proven in proposition 7 that,

> **Proposition 7.** Let $y$ be a sufficiently large real number, and let $\frac{a}{b}$ be
>   a rational number satisfying $\frac{a}{\log(y)} < \frac{a}{b} < 1 $ and $P^∗(b) \leq y$.
>   Then there is a set $S$ of integers satisfying:
>
> - (i) $S$ is contained in $[1, 2y^4]$;
> - (ii) $|S| = 2π^∗(y)$;
> - (iii) $a/b   = \sum_{s\in S} \frac 1 s$

After reviewing the proof of this proposition, if we don't care about the size, then we can actually prove the following (already contained in the proof of proposition 7).

**Proposition :** Let $y$ be a sufficiently large real number, and let $\frac{a}{b}$ be
a rational number satisfying $\frac{a}{\log(y)} < \frac{a}{b} < 1 $ and $P^∗(b) \leq y$.
Then there is a set $S$ of integers satisfying:

- (i) $S$ is contained in $[1, y^2]$;
- (iii) $a/b   = \sum_{s\in S} \frac 1 s$

As a corollary of this proposition, one can prove that for any large number $N$ such that 
$P^*(N)^2\leq N$ there exists a set $S\subset [1,N-1]$ such that :
$$\frac 1 n =(\frac 12+\frac 13 +\frac 1 6)- \sum_{s\in S} \frac 1 s  $$

By taking $\frac a b = \frac {n-1} n $, $y=\sqrt n $.