# Show that $4x^2-yz$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

Here is my problem.

$A=xy+yz+zx$, where $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$. It is known that if we add $1$ to $x$, and subtract $2$ from both $y$ and $z$, the value $A$ won't change. Prove that $-A$ is a square of whole number.

---

My attempt:

\begin{align}
A=xy+yz+zx
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
A=(x+1)(y-2)+(y-2)(z-2)+(z-2)(x+1)
\end{align}

comparing them we get

\begin{align}
4x+y+z=0.
\end{align}

Now we insert last equation to first equation:

\begin{align}
-A&=-xy-yz-zx\\
&=-x(y+z)-yz\\
&=4x^2-yz
\end{align}

From here I don't know how to show that $4x^2-yz$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Eliminate $x$ from your last equation using $x = -\frac{y+z}{4}$. You'll get $-A=(\frac{y-z}{2})^2$

Comment: Once you found that the necessary and sufficient condition is $4x+y+z=0$, you can substitute values to determine $-A$, and hence guess the expression. E.g. with $ x = -1, y = 2, z = 2$, we get $ -A = 0$, With $ x = -1, y = 4, z = 0 $, we get $ -A = 4$. After listing enough cases, you should be able to guess that $ -A = ((y-a) / 2 )^2$, and then can work on the algebraic manipulation.

Comment: @nrynn I got it, thanks. and since $y+z$ is even, so $y-z$ is even too.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419766/number-of-solution-for-xy-yz-zx-n/713998#713998

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we expand, we get
$$A=(x+1)(y-2)+(y-2)(z-2)+(z-2)(x+1)\quad =\quad x y + x z - 4 x + y z - y - z$$
Subtracting the original from this equation should be zero
$$(x y + x z - 4 x + y z - y - z)-(xy+yz+xz)=0\\
\implies 4x+y+z=0\implies z = -4 x - y$$
Substituting $z$ now allows the equation to be viewed more simply
$$xy+y(-4 x - y)+x(-4 x - y)= -4 x^2 - 4 x y - y^2=A\\
\implies A=-(4x+4xy+y^2)$$
$$\therefore -A=(2x+y)^2$$

\begin{align*}
\end{align*}